# Method signature and compiler disagree on struct-return-edness

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, llvm, clang

```
NSForwarding: warning: method signature and compiler 
disagree on struct-return-edness of 'mapRegion'.  
Signature thinks it does not return a struct, and compiler thinks it does.
```

This is a description of `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` I'm getting randomly at startup. Not when I have breakpoints disabled, of course.
If a random Clang developer stumbles upon this thread, please enlighten me on the meaning of "struct-return-edness".

[image: Stack]

What's around:

```
- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView regionDidChangeAnimated:(BOOL)animated
{
  [self fetchIfNecessary:mapView];
  [self.annotationController refresh:YES]; // EXC_BAD_ACCES is here but the mentoned 'mapRegion' is probably in a different method

  CGFloat minimumLatitudeDeltaToFetch = 0.2;
  self.shouldDisplayGetCloserMessage = @(mapView.region.span.latitudeDelta > minimumLatitudeDeltaToFetch);
}

- (void)fetchIfNecessary:(MKMapView *)mapView
{
  MKCoordinateRegion region1 = mapView.region;
  MKCoordinateRegion region2 = self.eventRequestClient.mapRegion;
  // Above is: @property (nonatomic, assign) MKCoordinateRegion mapRegion;

  BOOL didRegionChangeSignificantly = [MKRegionUtilities isRegion:region1 significantlyDifferentFromRegion:region2];
  if (didRegionChangeSignificantly) [self fetch];
}
```

Comment: I doubt anybody will solve this but it's the fourth unbelievably weird (= Google doesn't show any results) bug I'm getting in the past month and I… I don't think I can go on anymore.

Comment: It might be worth changing the name of your `mapRegion` property. `MKMapView` has a (non-documented) property named that, and the error seems to indicate contradictory information about how that property is defined.

Comment: Ooooh, nice call, @TomHarrington ! Yes, I once broke an entire project by naming an instance variable `firstResponder`. No class is documented as having such a property, but clearly there was a name conflict somewhere. Changing the name solved the problem.

Comment: The owner the `mapRegion` property is subclassed just from `NSObject` and there is no point where the class description could be changed at runtime by a third party.   Surely the class with your `firstResponder` property inherited from some UIKit class, didn't it?

Comment: As explained in the answer to that question, Objective-C basically requires that all methods for the same selector have the same type signature, even if they are defined on different classes with no common ancestor.  The reason is that you can send any message to an `id`, and the compiler needs to know what type signature to use.  By defining `mapRegion` with a different type signature that the one in the MapKit framework, you've made the compiler put conflicting information into your executable file.